# Add data to JSP's display table

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

```
<display:table name="example" class="FORM">
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.all_items_found" value=""/>
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.onepage" value=""/>
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.one_item_found" value=""/>
            <display:column property="userId" sortable="false" title="User ID" headerClass="sortable"/>
            <display:column property="dateAdded" sortable="false" title="Added Date" headerClass="sortable"/>
            <display:column property="statusDate" sortable="false" title="Status Date" headerClass="sortable"/>
            <display:column property="params" sortable="false" title="Parameters" headerClass="sortable"/>
            <display:column property="status" sortable="false" title="Status" headerClass="sortable"/>
        </display:table>
```

So I have this table in my JSP page. All the data gets set from an ArrayList in a java file like this:

```
ArrayList options = new ArrayList(); (Has data in it though....)
request.setAttribute("example", options);
```

How can I just add to this table dynamically? The information comes from an SQL query and I want to just be able to use an offset and add the new data.

Comment: The Java part is irrelevant as long as you want to manipulate the DOM on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add more data dynamically from SQL query, you can make Ajax query and then to add new rows to the current table.